# DLL in GAC references a file relatively ... where should I put it?

Tags: dll, gac

I have a third party dll that I need to install to the GAC. The dll needs access to a ini file that according to the documentation needs to be in the same location as the dll. If I install the dll into the GAC, what location should I copy the ini file to in order for the dll to find the ini file?

Comment: If two different applications use the DLL would that mean they have to share the ini settings ?

Comment: No, same ini settings for all applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can hold your nose, and navigate to the directory within the side-by-side assembly structure in the GAC in which the file is located and put it there. It will be a path something like "C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089". Do "Start menu -> run -> c:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL" - this is enough to get you past the windows view on the directory structure. Or, you can navigate to it directly in the command shell.

Comment: Yeah, I agree about the hold your nose part. But what are you gonna do, when someone ties your hands behind your back with their dll?

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Only thing I wanted to add is that for a .NET 1.1 dll it will be located in C:\windows\assembly\gac\ ...